# requireJS load non AMD common scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, requirejs

How do you load non-AMD complaint scripts as common in requireJS or should I just have to do it manually? I am speaking specifically of jQuery, bootstrap and some other little scripts needed globally by all my custom modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can still ask RequireJS to load the library but you need to use the "shim" functionality in the requirejs.config() call as specified here:

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

If I've understood what you are asking, here is an example (I didn't look to see if Bootstrap actually exposed a global or just mixed in with jQuery but you'll see the point):

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
     'jquery': 'path/to/jquery/jquery.min',
     'bootstrap': 'path/to/bootstrap/bootstrap.min'
  },
  shim: {
     'bootstrap': {
         deps: ['jquery'],
         exports: 'Bootstrap'
     }
  }
});

require(['bootstrap'], function(Bootstrap) {
   /* Because of the specified dependencies above, RequireJS will load 
     jQuery first and then Bootstrap, supplying the library into the  
     function signature so that you can use the "Bootstrap" variable  
     normally. */
});
```

If you also wanted `$` to be in scope for jQuery, you would need this:

```
require(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function($, Bootstrap) {
    // Use '$' and 'Bootstrap' normally here.
}
```

Comment: how can I expose it as global, without the need for a definition.

Comment: You could expose it globally by defining those things in `<script></script>` tags above your includes for RequireJS but I wouldn't recommend it.  Script loading should be done all or nothing in my opinion or you could get into some nasty timing errors down the road.